# how to use lit components using mutation observer so that we can use lit components in nextJs and lazy loading should work. Provide me workable code

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, web-component, lit

how to use lit components using mutation observer so that we can use those components in next js project and lazy loading is also possible. Provide me the complete workable code

I want to run web components made in lit in next js project so that lazy loading is possible. I have tried recently using mutation observer but getting error. I also have used methods like making the bundle file of the lit web components and then publishing it in the npm and installing the dependencies in the next js project but in this case lazy loading is not working. I want that lazy loading should be properly working in Next js whule using lit components..

Comment: Alas StackOverflow is about **helping** you with your own code. We are not here to do your job

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to understand that Next.js supports lazy loading of components using dynamic imports. This can be done with the next/dynamic module
For example, to lazily load a Lit component, you can do something like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const MyLitComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyLitComponent'));

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyLitComponent />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the code snippet above, MyLitComponent will only be loaded when the HomePage component is rendered.

However, if you want to observe changes in the DOM and load components accordingly, you'll need to use the Mutation Observer API

You can create a custom hook to encapsulate the Mutation Observer logic like this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useMutationObserver = (ref, options) => {
  const [mutationList, setMutationList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
        setMutationList(mutations);
      });

      observer.observe(ref.current, options);

      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [ref, options]);

  return mutationList;
};
```

Then, in your component, you can use this hook to observe changes and load your Lit component dynamically:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useMutationObserver } from '../hooks/useMutationObserver';

const MyLitComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/MyLitComponent'));

export default function HomePage() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const mutations = useMutationObserver(ref, { childList: true, subtree: true });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mutations.some((mutation) => mutation.type === 'childList')) {
      // Load MyLitComponent when a child node has been added or removed
    }
  }, [mutations]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {/* Other components */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

n this example, MyLitComponent will be loaded when a child node is added or removed from the div that the ref is attached to.

Remember that this is a simple example and you might need to adjust it to fit your requirements. For instance, you might want to add more conditions to the useEffect hook to determine when to load MyLitComponent.

Also, keep in mind that using dynamic imports might cause a flash of unstyled content (FOUC) because the component will not be loaded until the JavaScript for it is downloaded and parsed. You can mitigate this by displaying a loading state or placeholder content.

Please ensure that your Lit components are built and exported correctly, and that they're compatible with server-side rendering (SSR) which Next.js uses. If they're not compatible with SSR, you'll need to disable SSR for those components using the { ssr: false } option with next/dynamic.

Happy Coding :)